# Is there an upgrade to do Air-to-Ground damages?

Tags: airmech

In AirMech, I often wants to destroy ground units while flying. Is there a way - perhaps, with an upgrade - to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Warthog Airmech is capable of Air to Ground damage, Bomber as well. You could also get the unit "bombs" to give any airmech air to ground capabilities.

Comment: What about air-to-ground firing?

Comment: Warthog Only...

Comment: Just tried.. Its Warthog's secondary feature available after spending in-game ability points. It does only 50% damage ground-to-air or air-to-ground, but still it turns out to be badass feature.